# ROW_NUMBER() execution plan

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, sql-server-2008

Please consider this query:

```
SELECT num,
   *
FROM   (
       SELECT OrderID, CustomerID, EmployeeID, OrderDate, RequiredDate,
              ShippedDate,
              ROW_NUMBER() 
              OVER(ORDER BY OrderID) AS num
       FROM   Orders
   ) AS numbered
WHERE  NUM BETWEEN 0AND 100
```

when I execute this query and get the execution plan, it's like this:

[image: execution plan]

I want to know

1) What steps SQL Server 2008 pass to add `ROW_NUMBER()` in a query?

2) Why in first step in Execution plan we have `Clustered Index Scan`?

3) Why filtering cost is 2%? I mean why for getting appropriate data sql server does not perform a table scan? Does `ROW_NUMBER()` cause creating an index?

Comment: I wonder why some one vote -1 or vote for close!!!! what part of this question is wrong????

Comment: IMHO this is not *too localized*. It's a solid question about the execution plan for `ROW_NUMBER()` that uses a pretty trivial example most SQL programmers can understand.

Comment: I don't understand.does not `ROW_NUMBER()` belong to SQL programming? I just provide an example that help users understand it

Comment: I'm agreeing with you; it's a good question.

Comment: thanks @Yuck.I don't meant you.I mean users vote -1 **Unreasonable**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The Segment/Sequence Project portions of the plan relate to the use of ROW_NUMBER().
2. You have a clustered index scan because there is no WHERE clause on your inner SELECT, hence all rows of the table have to be returned.
3. The Filter relates to the WHERE clause on the outer SELECT.

Comment: about 3. consider when `ROW_NUMBER()` created and we have 1000000 record and we want 999900 to 1000000 records,Does swl server loop through all records(from 1 to 1000000) to get result?

Comment: @Rozhin - Yes it does. `ROW_NUMBER` paging queries can often be improved upon with rewrites. For example the QO can't currently consider using a narrow index to find the `999,900` record then switching over to a wider covering index just for the last 100 records. Good explanation of [Segment and Sequence Project Iterators](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2010/07/28/the-segment-and-sequence-project-iterators.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

1. That "Compute Scalar" part of the query is the `row_number` being created.
2. Because you're selecting every row from `Orders`, then numbering it, then selecting 1-100. That's a table (or in this case a clustered index) scan anyway you slice it.
3. No, indexes aren't created on the fly. It's gotta check the rows because the set doesn't come back ordered in your subquery.